# Is there any difference between $('selector1').find('selector2') and $('selector1 selector2')

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have 2 jquery expressions:

```
A) $('#frmSurveyHTML > .PreviewFormWrapper .MainControl[disqualifier]');
B) $('#frmSurveyHTML > .PreviewFormWrapper').find('.MainControl[disqualifier]');
```

Both expressions return different - different match.

**Expected Behaviour:-** Both expressions are different is manner of syntax; But for me they should select same element in DOM.

**Actual Behaviour:-**

- **A** - returns the selected element
- **B** - returns the empty

Please check screenshot -[image]

I am not able to understand why both expression returning different result; Is anyone known?

Comment: No difference in logic, there's a possible performance difference in browser implementation. It would only be slight though.

Comment: Both are the same, maybe you need to post your elements structure. See this jsfiddle to see that both select the same elements: https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/p9fwo0ra/